# Sending PHP value in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send PHP value using ajax but it is not running .Please Help.

```
$.ajax({
             url:"getuser.php",
            type:"GET",
             data:{ id2: name2,id:<?php  $_GET['id']; ?> },
              success:function(data){
             $("#detail").html(data);

               }
              });
```

Comment: edit your code <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<?php $_GET['id']; ?>
```

to

```
<?= $_GET['id'] ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Comment: Not Working @Danyal Sandeelo

Answer (score 0):

Code wise correction is  As mentioned in above answers is change below line:

```
<?php $_GET['id']; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

But make sure you will pass id as url parameter since you use $_GET method to assign value . For example:

http://localhost/YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY/filename.php?id=121

This must work.

Sample full functional code is below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test();">Click here</a>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
function test(){
    $.ajax({
             url:"getuser.php",
            type:"GET",
             data:{ id2: "1",id:<?php echo $_GET['id']?> },
              success:function(data){
                $("#detail").html(data);
               }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why id2 is 1.@Prajwal.

Comment: its just a number for reference used. if your java script has the variable with value assigned  'name2'(As per your example) u can just replace it as  { id2: name2,id:<?php  echo $_GET['id']; ?> }.